# XGBoost giving a static prediction of "0.5" randomly

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost

I am using a scikit-learn pipeline with XGBRegressor. 
Pipeline is working good without any error. When I am prediction with this pipeline, I am predicting the same data multiple times, Sometimes out of random the predictions are coming as 0.5 while the normal prediction range is (1000-10,000)

> eg :
>   (1258.2,1258.2,1258.2,1258.2,1258.2,1258.2,**0.5**,1258.2,1258.2,1258.2,1258.2)

- Input Data is exactly same
- Environment is same

  ```
  numeric_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
          ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='mean')),
          ('scaler', StandardScaler())])
      categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
          ('imputer',
           SimpleImputer(strategy='constant', fill_value='missing')),
          ('onehot', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))
      ])

  numeric_features = X.select_dtypes(
      include=['int64', 'float64']).columns
  categorical_features = X.select_dtypes(
      include=['object']).columns
  preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
      transformers=[
          ('num', numeric_transformer, numeric_features),
          ('cat', categorical_transformer, categorical_features)])

  # Number of trees
  n_estimators = [int(x) for x in
                  np.linspace(start=50, stop=1000, num=10)]
  # Maximum number of levels in tree
  max_depth = [int(x) for x in np.linspace(1, 32, 32, endpoint=True)]
  # Booster
  booster = ['gbtree', 'gblinear', 'dart']
  # selecting gamma
  gamma = [i / 10.0 for i in range(0, 5)]
  # Learning rate
  learning_rate = np.linspace(0.01, 0.2, 15)
  # Evaluation metric
  #         eval_metric = ['rmse','mae']
  # regularization
  reg_alpha = [1e-5, 1e-2, 0.1, 1, 100]
  reg_lambda = [1e-5, 1e-2, 0.1, 1, 100]
  # Min chile weight
  min_child_weight = list(range(1, 6, 2))
  # Samples
  subsample = [i / 10.0 for i in range(6, 10)]
  colsample_bytree = [i / 10.0 for i in range(6, 10)]

  # Create the random grid
  random_grid = {'n_estimators': n_estimators,
                 'max_depth': max_depth,
                 'booster': booster,
                 'gamma': gamma,
                 'learning_rate': learning_rate,
                 #                        'eval_metric' : eval_metric,
                 'reg_alpha': reg_alpha,
                 'reg_lambda': reg_lambda,
                 'min_child_weight': min_child_weight,
                 'subsample': subsample,
                 'colsample_bytree': colsample_bytree
                 }

  # Use the random grid to search for best hyperparameters
  # First create the base model to tune
  rf = xgboost.XGBRegressor(objective='reg:squarederror', n_jobs=4)
  # Random search of parameters, using 3 fold cross validation,
  # search across 100 different combinations, and use all available cores
  rf_random = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=rf,
                                 param_distributions=random_grid,
                                 n_iter=100,
                                 cv=3,
                                 verbose=0,
                                 random_state=42,
                                 n_jobs=4)

  pipe = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor', preprocessor),
                         ('regressor', rf_random)])

  pipe.fit(X, y)
  ```

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting some *unusually low* predictions, it's probably indicating that the dependent variable has outliers. I'd suggest you to read about it, and about the different strategies to tackle this problem, or recommendations.

Usually its not a good idea to consider all data samples for your model without outlier removal. This will lead to much worse and non-representative metrics.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is true. Outliers are already removed. The example I have given belongs to 1 observation. If I am predicting the same observation many times lets say out of 50 times I am getting this "0.5" result and even for other observations also I am getting exact "0.5". This is completely valid scenario. Please let me know if you have any more such scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because you have Nans or None in your target (y)